# How can an NPC communicate with the party over long distances?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

In the current story, the PC's are chasing after a traitor from their kingdom. They are working with the Spymaster to chase him down and catch or kill him. The Spymaster is going to suggest a pincer move to stop the traitor from simply running away.

I need a way the Spymaster can keep in contact with the party over long distances (10s of miles at the least). Preferably instant but it doesn't have be two-way, just short messages to each other would be perfect.

Are there any spells or magical items in 5th Edition D&D that can do this?

Homebrew answers will be accepted if they have been play-tested.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Sending*, from page 274 of the PHB seems like it should meet your needs.

It allows for short messages (25 words or less) and allows for immediate response. It's not limited by range, and is 3rd level Evocation.

Comment: that's perfect, a couple of Scrolls of Sending will do the job perfectly! thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you only require it once per day take a look at Sending Stones p199 of the DMG.

Also, Rary's Telepathic Bond or Telepathy are great solutions. The former has to be cast while everyone is within 30 feet but the latter has unlimited range and 24 hr duration.